# Get 500 error when i try to load my website with TinyMCE image upload enabled

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-upload, tinymce

So everything works fine on locahost on my xampp appache server, but when i move everything to the domain website i get the GET 500 error. i cant click buttons on website and my Database doesn't load... I am hosting domain on some provider.

Error in chrome
[image]

Error in chrome
[image]

And i checked the logs and couldn't find anything.

Here is my code:

```js
//TINYMCE EDITOR
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#mytextarea', //ID textareea 
    plugins: [
    'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
    'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
    'table emoticons template paste help'
  ],
    toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | ' + //VSE KA BO V EDITORJU
        'bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullscreen | ' +
        'forecolor backcolor emoticons | help',
    menu: {
        favs: {
            title: 'My Favorites',
            items: 'code visualaid | searchreplace | emoticons'
        }
    },
    menubar: 'favs file edit view insert format tools table help',
    content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }',
    paste_data_images: true, //Da lahko slike drag and drop
    mobile: { //Združljivo z telefonom
        menubar: true
    },
    entity_encoding : "raw",
    images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',
    //automatic_uploads: false,
    images_upload_base_path: 'img/',
    images_upload_handler: function(blobInfo, success, failure){
        
        var xhr, formData;
      
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.withCredentials = false;
            xhr.open('POST', 'postAcceptor.php');
      
            xhr.onload = function() {
            var json;
        
            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
                return;
            }
        
            json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        
            if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
                failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
                return;
            }
        
            success(json.location);
        };
      
        formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
      
        xhr.send(formData);
    }
        
    


});
```

```
    <?php
    // Allowed origins to upload images
    $accepted_origins = array("www.mydomain.com", "http://localhost");

    // Images upload path
    $imageFolder = "img/";

    reset($_FILES);
    $temp = current($_FILES);
    if(is_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'])){
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])){
            // Same-origin requests won't set an origin. If the origin is set, it must be valid.
            if(in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $accepted_origins)){
                header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
            }else{
                header("HTTP/1.1 403 Origin Denied");
                return;
            }
        }
      
        // Sanitize input
        if(preg_match("/([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])|([\.]{2,})/", $temp['name'])){
            header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid file name.");
            return;
        }
      
        // Verify extension
        if(!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), array("gif", "jpg", "png"))){
            header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid extension.");
            return;
        }
      
        // Accept upload if there was no origin, or if it is an accepted origin
        $filetowrite = $imageFolder . $temp['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'], $filetowrite);
      
        // Respond to the successful upload with JSON.
        echo json_encode(array('location' => $filetowrite));
    } else {
        // Notify editor that the upload failed
        header("HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error");
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4800344). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K, the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: I'd also recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: _"And i checked the logs and couldn't find anything."_ - check again. PHP will have logged the cause of the problem. You just need to find it.